# Keep the app awaken in background when [MPMusicPlayerApplicationController applicationQueuePlayer] is used to play the music

Tags: ios, multitasking, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

With iOS 10.3 Apple released new APIs in MediaPlayer framework that brings more control/power to the developer that want to play music stored on Apple Music/iTunes Match.  I’m talking about new applicationQueuePlayer and applicationMusicPlayer of MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.
The problem is of course with the multitasking. I'm building basically an alternative to Apple's own music player. But also I need to execute some code (mostly network connections) when the music is playing. Those new APIs requires to turn on background modes for the app (Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture), so music is playing when the user goes to home screen, but the app itself is suspended.
I've figured out that I can play silent audio so the app itself stays alive and maybe, maybe the app will be approved (as technically it's playing music in background and background mode capability must be turned on anyway). But I don't want to consume user's battery when the music is paused.
Even funnier: it seems, that new API is designed for the apps that stay alive in background, because on iOS 10.3.3 after changing the track via Control Center and tapping on the name of the song the system music app is opened instead of my app.
Imagine, that user pause the music from control center before arriving to work, then resumes it from control center. I don't want to eat user's battery when he's at work.
My question is: is there any way to keep the app live and respond to actions taken by the user?

Answer (score 0):

"The music player does not affect the Music app’s state. When your app moves to the background, the music player stops playing the current media."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/2817540-applicationqueueplayer

systemMusicPlayer will continue in the background, BUT, you have no access, or I think now (iOS11) limited access to the queue.

I think you still need to use some form of AVPlayer ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer ) if you want granular control over what goes on, but then you will need to implement all the things that update the lock screen etc on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
This isn't an answer as AVPlayer can't be used to play tracks from Apple Music and I don't want to affect Music app's state.